# How to read the subtitles in Totem immediately?

Tags: totem

I have successfully managed to load subtitles in Totem.

I checked the "Automatically load subtitle files when movie is loaded" option.

The subtitles are run.

**The problem**: When I start the movie forward or backward, subtitles may take some time to reappear.

Comment: what do you mean by start the movie forward or backward? Do you mean the seek time (fast-forward/rewind) ? or do you mean some other file in the playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the subtitles are not reappearing immediately. This delay usually happens when you load a different subtitle while watching. But I would suggest that you get smplayer. It is an awesome player that has superb subtitle support. I also recommend gecko-mediaplayer plugin instead of the totem-mozilla plugin.